# Css in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to display a status message in javascript and would like to include some css to that staus message.Can anyone help me out with this?

Now I have two css classes named Available and Not available for the available I need to apply the Available css class and for not available I need to append the NotAvailable css class.

Here is my javascript code:

```
   function OnSuccess(response) {
        var mesg = $("#mesg")[0];

        switch (response.d) {
            case "true":
                mesg.style.color = "green";
                mesg.innerHTML = "Available";
                break;
            case "false":
                //                    mesg.style.color = "red";
                mesg.innerHTML = "Not Available";
                break;
            case "error":
                //                    mesg.style.color = "red";
                mesg.innerHTML = "Error occured";
                break;
        }
    }
    function OnChange(txt) {
        $("#mesg")[0].innerHTML = "";

    }
```

This is my Css:

```
    .Available
            {
                position: absolute;
                width: auto;
                margin-left: 30px;
                border: 1px solid #349534;
                background: #C9FFCA;
                padding: 3px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #008000;
            }

    .NotAvailable
{
     position:absolute;
     width:auto;
     margin-left:30px;
     border:1px solid #CC0000;
     background:#F7CBCA;
     padding:3px;
     font-weight:bold;
     color:#CC0000;
    }
```

Comment: a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you use `.NotAvaiable` and `.Avaiable` classes? Won't it be better to use `#mesg` and '#mesg.NotAvaiable' to make by default your container either avaiable or not available? Then you just toggle one class and your code would be much clearer.

Comment: Sure I will try that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mesg.addClass('Available');
mesg.removeClass('NotAvailable');
```

and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable answers

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, you can say thank you in Stackoverflow by accepting an answer with the tick mark to the left ;)

Comment: Yes I do but It takes me 9 mins to accept that as per rules as I have less reputation.

Comment: @user944919 : Nothing to do with reputation in this. Everyone has to wait for 10 minutes after the question is being asked to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.addClass(cssClassName)`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) adn [`.removeClass(cssClassName)`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) method in jquery.

Something like this:

```
     switch (response.d) {
        case "true":
            mesg.removeClass('NotAvailable').addClass('Available');
            mesg.innerHTML = "Available";
            break;
        case "false":
            mesg.removeClass('Available').addClass('NotAvailable');
            mesg.innerHTML = "Not Available";
            break;
        case "error":
            mesg.removeClass('Available').addClass('NotAvailable');
            mesg.innerHTML = "Error occured";
            break;
    }
```

I have used removeClass(cssClass) and then addClass(className) because you are using same element to change class.

Also you can try [`.toggleClass(cssClassName)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: Lol we are really going for higher and higher levels of rewriting the code huh?

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable answers

Comment: @Dave: as far as my key board has `CTRL`, `C` and `V` buttons I doesn't feel tedious in rewriting code with modification. Actually it also helps OP.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier than you think.  You just need to change those innerHTML lines to:

```
mesg.html("<div class='Available'>Available</div>");

mesg.html("<div class='Available'>Not Available</div>");
```

`.html()` is just jQuery's more compatible way of setting the innerHTML.  And html really means html... so you can do anything there you can do in a regular web page!

Comment: in that case: use the `.html();` function (jQuery-function)

Comment: True, that would be slightly more correct : ) I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable answers

Answer (score 1):

jQuery also has a `.css()` function. Maybe that will do the trick?

Or do you want to add a class to your mesg? in that case: `$("#mesg").addClass("classOfYourChoice");`

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable answers