# Set css attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my function set css attributes like as jquery

```
that.getNode = function() {
    return element;   // element is HTML node
};    


that.css = function(obj) {
    var node = that.getNode(),
        attr;
    if (node && node.style) {
        for (attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr) && node.style.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                node.style[attr] = obj[attr];
            }
        }
    }
    return that;
};
```

Then I call, it runs on Chrome normally but can't work on IE9 or firefox

```
that.css({
    border: "1px solid black"
});
```

Comment: there are similar questions on SO, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527447/css-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the following returns `false` in some browsers:

```
node.style.hasOwnProperty(attr)
```

In these cases, the properties are being inherited from a `prototype` rather than *owned* by the `Object` (`node.style`) itself.

If you want to test that the property exists, whether owned or inherited, you can try the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
attr in node.style
```

In context:

```
that.css = function(obj) {
    var node = that.getNode(),
        attr;
    if (node && node.style) {
        for (attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr) && attr in node.style) {
                node.style[attr] = obj[attr];
            }
        }
    }
    return that;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a **[Cross-browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser)** solution by hand is lot of work, I recommend using some JavaScript Framework like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), it will do the hard work for you.

If you choose JQuery you have a function named .CSS and you could do this task in 1 line, for example:

You have an HTML element:

```
<div id="someID"> Content </div>
```

right? so you want to add some CSS Classes to this DIV, you only need to say to JQuery which node in the HTML DOM want to select and with the function .CSS you can set some CSS Attributes (and other things):

```
$("#someID").css("SOME-ATTRIbute","SOME-VALUE");
```

(#someID is the ID of the element, .CSS is the function)

easy eh?, Use JQuery or any other Javascript Frameworks that will help you to do a cross-browser application.

PS: sorry for my english